# Talend Studio Error during launch a job on a Job server

Tags: talend

i have a problem during a job's execution on a Job server.
I have the Talend 7.3.1 version.

When i try to run a Job on a target Job server i receive the following error:

```
Execution failed : java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sun Jan 17 01:06:12 CET 2021
[NotAfter: Sun Jan 17 01:06:12 CET 2021]
```

Someone knows how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: "CertificateExpiredException". Did you check your license on TMC/TAC ? it seems to be expired

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply  *Patch_20201215_TPS-4576_v1* to your TAC installation.

See :
https://community.talend.com/s/article/REQUIRED-by-Jan-17-2021-Mandatory-Talend-Certificate-update-for-Talend-v7-0-v7-1-v7-2-v7-3

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [disable offline mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhVBN.png),
then re-sync -> re,build

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).