# Error message in Talend tool connecting with server - How to resolve this issue

Tags: server, talend

Error message in  Talend tool connecting with server - How to resolve this issue

Execution failed : java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sun Jan 17 05:36:12 IST 2021
[NotAfter: Sun Jan 17 05:36:12 IST 2021]

Comment: Can you say which server ?

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535000/talend-studio-error-during-launch-a-job-on-a-job-server

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using a subscription product that comes with support. You can find the required steps here:
https://community.talend.com/s/article/FAQ-for-REQUIRED-by-Jan-17-2021-Mandatory-Talend-Certificate-update-for-Talend-On-premises-and-cloud?language=en_US

Applying the latest cumulative patch should fix your problem.